# How to prove that two representations are inequivalent?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Here is the question, I have two representations for *SU(3)* group, say $\frac{1}{2} \lambda _i$ and $- \frac{1}{2} \lambda _i^*$, how do I prove that they are not equivalent?

Comment: You can check whether their characters are equal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Are their characters not the same?